# Itertools and customizing list

Tags: python, python-itertools

So I have a list of teams:

```
teams = ["Team A", "Team B", "Team C", "Team D",] # ... etc.
```

What I'm trying to do is find all the possible match ups that that exist between these teams.  I figured out I could do this:

```
for x in itertools.product(teams,teams):
   teams_list.append([x[0],x[1]])
```

Eventually what I want to do is run a check to make sure each matchup is in there once, as well as taking each matchup and creating a unique url string from the 2 names.  Is this the proper way to go about it, because when i try playing around with the teams_list I have tuple issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), not `product`:

```
teams_list = list(itertools.combinations(teams, 2))
```